# String with multiple fonts and textSize in the same textView

Tags: android, string, textview

I have to put in the same textView a string with substrings of different sizes and colors. How can I do?

[image]

Comment: write html code and use Html.fromHtml() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `String` with `HTML tags` and set this `String` to `TextView` as `Html.fromHtml` like below:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt)).setText(
                        Html.fromHtml("<Font color=\'" + "#457548"
                                + "'\" >" + "your text"
                                + "</Font>"), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
```

More information go to: [how-display-html-android](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/how-display-html-android)

Answer (score 0):

You could attach html notation to the text, or put a textview for each different size and color in a linearlayout, why does it have to be strictly in one textview?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use HTML, you can use [spannables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) in a custom view.

Have a look at some old questions those can give you some hints:

1. [spannable on android for textView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840247/spannable-on-android-for-textview)
2. [Android EditText : How to apply Foreground color span as you type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327817/android-edittext-how-to-apply-foreground-color-span-as-you-type)

Answer (score 0):

Android has SpannableString that can be set in a textView. Each SpannableString can have a different color, font , onCLick() and so on. Multiple SpanableStrings can be set to a single texview.