# Android EditText change color of a single word

Tags: android

How do you go about changing the color of a single word in a EditText ? Meaning all words will be once color and one single word will be a different color.

Kind Regards

Comment: Try format the string with html

Comment: Use `SpannableString`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **ForegroundColorSpan**

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(yourText);
ForegroundColorSpan colorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(
        context.getResources()
        // Specify your color
        .getColor(R.color.your_font_color));
realPrice.setSpan(colorSpan,
         0, // Start index of the single word
         1, // End index of the single word
         Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
yourEditText.setText(ssb);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this like below image

[image]

You can implement this for EditText also. See [here](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring) full details tutorial.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25874987/177790 - here is a working example for EditText

Comment: @slott. Thank you my man. I did a number of unnecessary string modifications but never really got it worked. The answer on your url you shared hit the nail. So simple and working flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
String text = "<font color=#0000ff>sample</font> <font color=#ff0000>text</font>";
    edittext.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```